# Shorthand for exporting an import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been meaning to do this with BabelJS, however I'm not sure whether Babel or the specifications support it at the moment.

Given `Outer.js`:

```
export default function() { }
```

The example below does not work.

```
export Outer from './Outer'
```

With CommonJS modules, this could be easily written as

```
exports.x = require('./x');
```

Comment: You can use:

```js
export * from './Outer';
```

Comment: Thanks! I just cleared things a bit by adding an additional info of what `Outer.js` may contain (a `module.exports` or `export default`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of **April 3, 2015**, the **BabelJS** team has released `v5.0` 3 days ago which includes support for the said shorthand as stated in their [blog post](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/03/31/5.0.0/).

> Lee Byron's stage 1 additional export-from statements proposal completes the symmetry between import and export statement, allowing you to easily export namespaces and defaults from external modules without modifying the local scope.
>
> **Exporting a default**
>
> ```
> export foo from "bar";
> ```
>
> equivalent to:
>
> ```
> import _foo from "bar";
> export { _foo as foo };
> ```

**Old Answer**:

This export notation

```
export v from "mod";
```

does not supported in ES6 (look at supported examples [in the specification](https://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#table-42)), but it can be supported in ES7 (look at [this proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from)).

To achieve *exactly* the same result you must use `import` for now:

```
import Outer from './Outer';
export {Outer};
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a question -- if you're familiar with BabelJS (formerly `6to5`), can it be assumed that their `experimental` option supports the proposal? Because I'm transpiling my code with BabelJS (and webpack) with the `experimental` option set to `true`, however it does not seem to work.

Comment: @srph As far as I know babel does not support it nor without `experimental` flag, not with it. I don't know about has the babel team plans to implement this proposal in near future or not. But after all the proposal has only stage 1. When it will be stage 2, it'll have more sense for babel to implement it then it has now.

Comment: @srph  I'll corrected link to the blog post. Thanks, for update!

Comment: As a gotchya, if you have ismorphic modules make sure you have compatible babel options in webpack and .babelrc. Otherwise your browser bundle and node modules won't be compatibly transpiled.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript 1.5 also supports the ES 2015 additional export-from statements syntax:

```
export { default as Injector } from './lib/Injector';
```

Which generates the following ES5:

```
var Injector_1 = require('./lib/Injector');
exports.Injector = Injector_1.default;
```